# Is there a way to include location information by default in images taken through Glass?

Tags: exif, google-mirror-api, google-glass

At present, when I go to Plus and look at photos taken through Glass, I see metadata like this:

```
Location    Add a location
Date taken   6/7/13, 1:09 PM
Dimensions   2528 x 1856
File name    20130607_130926_201.jpg
File size    1.49M
Camera   Glass 1
Focal Length     2.95mm
Exposure     -
F Number     f/2.48
ISO  -
Camera make  Google
Flash    Not used
Exposure Bias    -
Views    -
```

I'd love to use the Glass' built-in GPS (or even my Android's GPS, if necessary) to add a location to the image.

My hack is to subscribe to the user's Locations and immediately query for latest location upon receipt of a photo. However, there are obvious accuracy limitations to this approach.

...is there a setting I'm missing somewhere that lets me enable this? (Asking for more metadata, like ISO and exposure, will probably come in another question or a more direct request to Google)

Thanks!

AKA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location information is not included in the EXIF data on photos taken by Glass.

But there is one simplification that we can make to your current solution. The `timelineItem` also contains [location information](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#location). You can use this instead of making an additional request to the `locations` collection.

This should contain location at the time the original timeline item is created (when the photo is taken), but there's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=42) which causes it to be stale. The data is no less accurate than what you're already fetching, though, so at least it will save you a request to the API.